# Should I ship my vendor directory of composer with GIT

Tags: php, github, phpunit, composer-php, vendor

I want to use the autoloader generated by composer for my unit tests to load classes automatically.

Now I don't know if I should commit my vendor directory to my git repo. A pro is that everyone who clones my repo immediately can run the phpUnit tests. A con is that I ship a lot of proprietary code with my repo.

Should I insist that the user who clones my repo has to run `composer install` first and therefor has to have composer "installed"?

Is it a solution to don't commit vendor directory into my git repo but pack it into a release branch so that my application runs out of the box?

Comment: Do not ship, everyone should use composer install. This resolves the dependencies for them, you can't anticipate them.

Comment: So should I link to the `vendor/autoload.php` in my `phpunit.xml` even if I don't ship the `vendor` directory with my repo?

Btw to the downvoter: I hate drive by down votes! Leave at least a comment why something with my question is wrong.

Comment: You can do that, no worries. For a rollout of the code composer install ist mandatory, so the classes will be there.

Comment: You probably should even include PHPUnit as a development dependency in your composer.json file. If you don't, you would silently assume that whoever wants to run your tests will have PHPUnit installed. That's exactly the same as assuming they have Composer installed.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [official recommendation](https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#installing-dependencies) is to ignore `vendor/`:

> **Tip:** If you are using git for your project, you probably want to add `vendor` into your `.gitignore`. You really don't want to add all of that code to your repository.

Make sure to include both your `composer.json` and `composer.lock` files, though.

Comment: What if Composer is unavailable at a time when you need a deploy? What if it is cracked and malicious code gets into libraries?

Comment: @Meglio, the Composer folks recommend having it available when you deploy. But if you can't for some reason you'll have to get dependencies some other way. Please read https://getcomposer.org/doc/faqs/should-i-commit-the-dependencies-in-my-vendor-directory.md. I'm not really sure how your "cracked and malicious code" comment is relevant here—are you worried about having a different version of a library in production vs. development?

Comment: there have been cases when malicious code is found in public repositories, CDN resources etc. Relying on 3rd party resources to fetch pieces of code from at a time of deployment may infringe various compliances. Re "compose unavailable", I mean the repository itself being offline – which is just another risk.

Comment: @Meglio, nobody is telling you that you _can't_ track your `vendor/` directory. And yes, like virtually all choices in tech, there are tradeoffs. I'm simply pointing you to the official recommendations from the project. This is how Composer is designed to be used. (Unofficial recommendations are off-topic here as they are primarily opinion-based.) In any case, most dependency managers, including Composer, have integrity checking built in. Take a look at `composer.lock`: it lists exact versions and checksums. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/31911237/354577, for example.

Comment: Still, the question didn't ask about the official recommendations specifically.

Comment: @Meglio, that's the only way the question can be interpreted and remain on-topic. But it looks like you're trying to find something that reinforces your position instead of learning something. Arguing here is counterproductive. Feel free to add your own answer to this question if you want to suggest another solution. If you do this, please take the time to consider, and describe, the _drawbacks_ of your strategy and not just the benefits. Again, this decision has tradeoffs and it's important to consider them.

Comment: Those official recommendations should not be obligations.
1/ Thoses libraries almost never change, so it's not so costly for the the repo.
2/ When its work locally, I want it to work remotely : I want to 100% master the content of my vendors, without 3rd party software complexity implied.