# what is shasum in composer.lock?

Tags: php, apache2, composer-php

I want to upgrade packages framework and I modified my composer.lock in 
but i don't understand shasum

```
"dist": {

            "type": "zip",

            "url": "http://www.packages/dist/packages.zip",

            "reference": "83547c3fa8a8fa95aa40b00afc5117d2d38a9f00",

            "shasum": "75c9588c293b5893c07ba49ab28e28e0eea52f25"
        },
```

Comment: What don't you understand? What exactly is your question?

Comment: Pardon can you please read the title !

Comment: I have read the title. I'm asking you to be more specific.

Comment: I just don't understand what is shasum and the purpose of it ?

Comment: @kittykittybangbang really thanks for trying to help

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `shasum` is the SHA1 checksum for the downloaded ZIP to verify that it isn't corrupt or wasn't tampered with. If it's not the same as the one provided in composer.lock, it means the file that was downloaded is incomplete or incorrect, and composer will refuse to install the package.

Comment: Thanks you so much ! I understand now !